# Android: VideoView can't play video

Tags: android, android-videoview

im trying to get a basic video player working for an android application im working on but whenever i try to play the video i get an error saying "cant play video". Im certain the video is in supported formats and ive tried converting it between several of the supported formats on top of that so i assume its an issue with my code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView1);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setVideoPath("TravelAppTopic4/res/raw/canadavid.mp4");

        videoView.start();  
    }
```

thanks in advance for any help

edit:im testing on both a virtual device and an S3 to the same result.

Comment: The path seems wrong.

Comment: sorry but in what way?

Comment: Have you tried with a .3gp video? Look at if your video is not 0Byte big, those are typical reasons for this error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VideoScreen extends Activity{
private MediaController controller;
Context _ctx = VideoScreen.this;

private Thread thread;
ProgressBar progressBar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone_video_screen);



    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    controller = new MediaController(VideoScreen.this);
    video.setMediaController(controller);

    video.setVideoPath(_url);
    video.requestFocus();
    video.start();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,
                        int arg2) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

        }
    });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw. canadavid));
```